# Regular Expression for FileTypes

Tags: python, regex

I'm using an application which has the following line in it:

```
ACCEPT_FILE_TYPES = re.compile('image/(gif|p?jpeg|(x-)?png)')
```

Obviously, it limits uploads to **images** of the specified extensions. But I plan to use it for uploading these formats (perhaps even more than that)

- *Microsoft Office files* (.doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, etc.)
- *Adobe Reader* (.pdf)
- *And probably archives* (.rar, .zip, .7z)

I guess it needs to be rewritten to the following form:

```
ACCEPT_FILE_TYPES = re.compile('/(docx?|xlsx?|pdf|rar|zip|7z)')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Comment: So what's the question? What doesn't work with the last version you provided?

Comment: I tested it and it didn't work. It doesn't allow files of any type now. I'm not good with regex.

I've seen them use 'video/(avi|mp4)' for videos. Can't understand what's the trick here.

Comment: I think you would be better off determining the file type using the host environment, rather than guessing by the extension.

Comment: Do you match the regex to the extension or to the mime type? If you use the extension, remove the `/` at the beginning (or use `\.` instead).

Comment: @waleed-khan I guess, I will need to work on that a little bit. No idea how to do it though.

Comment: @tobias-k I tried that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those aren't file extensions that you're trying to match but **MIME types**.

The MIME types for common image formats happen to be quite straightforward, for example:

```
image/png
image/jpeg
image/gif
```

But most other types are not, but instead are using MIME types like these:

```
.pdf    application/pdf

.doc    application/msword
.xls    application/vnd.ms-excel

.rar    application/x-rar-compressed
.7z     application/x-7z-compressed
.zip    application/zip

.xlsx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
.xltx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template
.potx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template
.ppsx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow
.pptx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
.sldx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide
.docx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
.dotx   application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template
```

*Note: These are only the most commonly used MIME types for the respective file formats. The IANA is the official authority for registering MIME types, but in the wild you'll encounter many different variations, depending on the programs that use them (Mail clients, browsers, web servers, ...).*

So you shouldn't be matching them by using regular expressions, but instead maintain a registry of allowed MIME types (can be a simple Python list, or a dictionary if you want to really make sure and account for variants).

Read up on [MIME types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type), check the [IANA MIME Media Types list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html) as an authoritative source for registered MIME types and use the Python [**`mimetypes`** module](http://docs.python.org/library/mimetypes.html) to look up mimetypes by file extensior or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you've helped a lot. Tested, it works. And thanks for the resources as well.

Answer (score 0):

This function evaluates if a given URI corresponds to a file with a valid mime-type.

```
import mimetypes

a = 'http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html'
b = '/data/Python.txt'
c = 532
d = u'dkakasdkjdjakdjadjfalskdjfalk'
e = u'http://tobeclever.ru/download/martin_george_a_game_of_thrones.pdf'

# The optional strict argument is a flag specifying whether the list
# of known MIME types is limited to only the official types registered
# with IANA. When strict is True (the default), only the IANA types are
# supported; when strict is False, some additional non-standard but commonly
# used MIME types are also recognized.

def mimetype_validator(x):
    try:
        (guessed_type, encoding_guessed) = mimetypes.guess_type(x, strict=True)
        return True if guessed_type in mimetypes.types_map.values() else False
    except:
        return False

print mimetype_validator(a)
print mimetype_validator(b)
print mimetype_validator(c)
print mimetype_validator(d)
print mimetype_validator(e)
```

Gives:

```
True
True
False
False
True
```